# RabbitMQ fails to startup when I start a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, rabbitmq, containers, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed RabbitMQ inside a docker container on Ubuntu 20.04 using the following steps: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-rabbitmq-server-on-ubuntu-linux/

It works as expected and I can use it in a sample python program.

After installation I exit the container and save it to a new docker image using:

```
docker commit *my_container_id* *my_new_container_name*
docker save -o image_with_rabbitmq.tar *my_new_container_name*
```

I then load this new image and run it like so:

```
docker load -i image_with_rabbitmq.tar
docker run --rm --gpus all -it *my_image_id*
```

But now I find that I cannot start or use rabbitmq anymore.  I get the following error:

```
service rabbitmq-server status
Distribution failed: {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :net_kernel, {:EXIT, :nodistribution}}}, {:child, :undefined, :net_sup_dynamic, {:erl_distribution, :start_link, [[:"rabbitmqcli-184-rabbit@231b2003671d", :shortnames, 15000], false, :net_sup_dynamic]}, :permanent, false, 1000, :supervisor, [:erl_distribution]}}
```

Here is the startup log message:

```
cat /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err 

BOOT FAILED
===========
Exception during startup:

error:{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,   {'EXIT',nodistribution}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_link,[[rabbit_prelaunch_9642@localhost,shortnames],false,net_sup_dynamic]},permanent,false,1000,supervisor,[erl_distribution]}}}}

rabbit_prelaunch_dist:duplicate_node_check/1, line 78
rabbit_prelaunch_dist:setup/1, line 23
rabbit_prelaunch:do_run/0, line 115
rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase/0, line 32
supervisor:do_start_child_i/3, line 414
supervisor:do_start_child/2, line 400
supervisor:-start_children/2-fun-0-/3, line 384
supervisor:children_map/4, line 1250

Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_link,[[rabbit_prelaunch_9642@localhost,shortnames],false,net_sup_dynamic]},permanent,false,1000,supervisor,[erl_distribution]}}}}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

How can I ensure this starts up properly when my container starts?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  "I installed some software and committed it", in particular, is _not_ reproducible; a good start would be to write a Dockerfile that performs the installation steps and include that in the question.

Comment: The problem I have is that I have inherited a docker image in the form of a .tar file from another developer.  I do not have the original Dockerfile.

Comment: In order to help we need to be able to reproduce the error. Is possible host this image in somewhere (if not exist sensitive data)?

Comment: Please provide `docker history [OPTIONS] IMAGE`.

Comment: Any reason why you and your other developer didn't just use any of rabbitmq docker images available on dockerhub? Or at least create dockerfile that contains the installation steps in the link you refered to. Why must you start with a base ubuntu container and install rabbitmq in it before saving the state? The error seems like it stored the hostname of previous container and attempted to connect to it on the next docker run, which was assigned a different hostname.